# Проблема с запуском Powershell консоли Sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, active-directory

Выдает ошибку `"Powershell: The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered"`. Ферма у меня не сконфигурирована, поэтому известное решение с дачей прав на базу - не актуально т.к. баз у меня ещё никаких не создано. Запускаю от имени администратора.

Изначально было создано 2 сервера (2012R2) на **Hyper-V**, один производственный, а другой тестовый, в одном домене. На тестовом много раз пересоздавал ферму и в случае чего откатывался до предыдущего снапшота (так же удалял все базы) и все по новой делал. Много раз это работало, но в один прекрасный момент я не мог подключиться к серверу, заход с хост машины на сервер дал ошибку: `"The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."` Решаем просто перепропиской в домен сервера. Но после у меня все время вываливалась консоль ШП с данной ошибкой т.е. сконфигурировать с её помощью ШП не представляется возможным. Притом на производственном тоже самое случилось, хотя я его с момента установки там ШП - не трогал, а консоль ШП там запускалась после установки.

На англ. язычном [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679863/powershell-the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid) мне подсказали и я сам к такому же выводу пришел, что видимо где-то в `Active Directory` хранятся сведения о конфигурации моей фермы. Немного сложностей добавляет, что в домене уже есть производственный ШП 2010.

Так же из опытов вышло, что если я создам приложение центрального администрирования через автоматический мастер, то ШП консоль заработает т.е. видимо в AD данные обновляются и все хорошо, но мне все же это нужно сделать самому через **Powershell SP2013**.

Answer (score 1):

Если ферма/ConfigDB не создана, то можно её создать [командой](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607838.aspx) `New-SPConfigurationDatabase`:

```
New-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName "SharePointConfigDB1" -DatabaseServer "SQL-01" -Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -force) -FarmCredentials (Get-Credential)
```